# Android google maps with marker inside fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I would like to display a google map inside a fragment. A world map is dipslayed but the markers will be ignored. 
Hopefully some can help me with my problem.
Please find below my code:

MapsFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null, false);
        initilizeMap();
        return root;
    }

    private void initilizeMap()
    {
        SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
        }
        if (mSupportMapFragment != null)
        {
            GoogleMap googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
            if (googleMap != null)
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.1253,10.5868)));
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_map.xml (Layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.03"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The APIKey and permission are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `getMap()`method, it is deprecated. You should use `getMapAsync()`. Check out [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment#getMapAsync%28com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback%29). Your mapsFragments needs to implement the [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) interface.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the hint! Works now.